# How Do I Make Ctrl-f Always Work in Tabulator Plus Questions on Pagination and Height?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, browser, tabulator

How do you make it possible to search for any item in the table regardless of the number of rows loaded using ctrl-f?

I have a large table consisting of over 10,000 rows.

So, far I have tried using Pagination. This works regardless of how large I change the "paginationSize".

Is there a way to make the pagination controls always visible regardless of paginationSize?

Right now setting the paginationSize to certain amounts will need a scroll bar to view the pagination controls.

Also when using pagination if I include a height to the table then ctr-f cannot find everything on any page.

How does the height setting affect the number of rows loaded?

How do I figure how many rows the table will load based on the height setting?

With both of those questions in mind, how do you know how many of the loaded rows will be searchable with ctrl-f

It says in the documentation "The virtual DOM renders a number of rows above and below the visible rows to ensure a smooth scrolling experience." What determines the number of rows above and below the visible rows?

Finally is there a better way to make ctrl-f always work on the table besides using pagination?

```
// Creating the tabulator table
var table = new Tabulator('#themeTestCaseMetricsTable', {
    height:"100%",
    pagination:"local",
    paginationSize:100,
    layout: "fitDataFill",
    cssClass: "column data",
    responsiveLayout: true,
    tooltips: true,
    // "safe" turns off auto-escaping
    columns: {{columns|safe}},
    data: {{rows|safe}},
    persistenceMode: "local",
    persistence: {
        columns: true
    }
});
```

Appreciate any help and feedback

Answer (score 0):

#### Ctrl+f

Tabulator uses a virtual DOM to improve render efficiency on large data sets, this means that only the visible rows actually exist, as you scroll rows are created and destroyed in realtime as they become visible. therefore you cannot search the table in that way.

The `ctrl+f` feature of browsers is more of a convenience feature of browser and it is bad UX to expect your users to use this to find things, if you want users to be able to search a table, you should add a search input and use the built in table [Filter Functionality](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/filter). you can see an example of this on the [Tabulator Home Page](http://tabulator.info/) where it lets you filter the table by the name column

That being said you can disable the virtual DOM by setting the `virtualDom` property to `false` although this will result in the table no longer scrolling and the table will take a long time to load if displaying large data sets

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    virtualDom:false, //disable virtual DOM rendering
});
```

#### paginationSize

You are having this issue because you are setting both a page size and a height, if you want the table to resize to fit the height of a page of data you should not set the height. if you would like the page to take up the height of the table you should not set the page size

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. But I am still confused. 

Is there a way to make the pagination controls always visible regardless of paginationSize? 
Also, why does a height setting that is smaller than the pagination size prevent ctrl-f from working? 

Setting the pagination size to any amount always results in the ctrl-f working, but this is not the case when you set the height with pagination without a pagination size. 

Why does the table not return rows in pagination when you disable the virtual dom?

Comment: This is because Tabulator uses a virtual DOM as described above, rows not visible on the table do not actually exist, there is nothing for the search to find, they are only added to the table as you scroll